# Localities around a particular latlang

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-places-api

I require list of localities around a particular latitude and longitude through Google Places.
Currently I'm making a call as

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=12.96207210,77.71577370&radius=3700&types=political&sensor=false&key=API_KEY

However,it is returning only those places which are approximately 3700 m far from that place.
I require all places returned in the output.

Comment: Do you mean that all of the results returned are actually about 3700 meters in distance from your LatLng? And you would like to include results from 0 m - 3700 m from your location? How many results are included in your response?

Comment: ideally there should have been 11-12 results,but its only returning 2 results.It may be due to the distance being taken as nearly 3.7 km and not the range between 0-3.7km,i think

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to retrieve all locality results close to you, as you are `type` filtering your request by type `political`.

Unfortunately the Google Places API is not designed for this and will only returning two political and locality results per request for area identification.

If you think that returning more than two political or locality results per request would be a useful feature for the Google Places API, you can submit a 'Places API - Feature Request' [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Please suggest me a suitable alternative if available in Gmaps/Gplaces or any other API which can give localities around a particular latlang.